# Knocking/thumping sound from rear wheels (Ford Escape)

Tags: ford, noise, escape, rear

I've been getting this loud knocking / thumping sound from the rear wheels in my 2008 Ford Escape but only when I'm braking. Could it be the bearings or suspension or ...?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!